# serverless.yml - How to force numbers not to be converted to strings?

Tags: types, aws-lambda, yaml, serverless-framework

I'm running into an odd behaviour. I have a YAML file `serverless.yml` (from the https://serverless.com/framework) that defines some variables, some of them are integer, like:

```
TEMPLATE_ID_CONTACT_REQUEST: 111
```

When I load that file locally, number aren't converted to string. But when I deploy it on AWS, numbers are automatically converted to strings.

When I run it locally, I use something that simulates AWS Lambda behaviour, may be related?

Anyway, I tried to find a way of forcing types in YAML files, but didn't find anything that works so far. And I cannot use a custom YAML file loader (AFAIK) because the serverless.yml file is loaded from the Serverless framework itself.

Comment: The issue only happens on AWS though, I don't need to do anything more locally, it works already as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're setting those variables as [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) and accessing them using `process.env`, the values should always be strings.

From [node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

If you need that value to be an integer, perhaps use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)? Running `parseInt` on an integer works fine, so should work locally as well.

Comment: Alright, that's exactly what actually happens. It never occurred to me that it could be because of the `process.env` behaviour, I thought it was related to YAML parsing. Thanks for the hint!